Hover effect is not applyed in CSS. What is the exact problem?
I am trying to build Search List for the Search Bar and the list should be change color when cursor is placed their and got selected when clicked from list of item shown.
searchlist.jsx:
import React from 'react'
import { FaSearch } from 'react-icons/fa';
import './SearchList.css';

function SearchList({TitleArray,setSearchQuery}) {
  return (
    <div className="Container_SearchList">
    { TitleArray.map(m => {
      return (
        <p
          key={m}
          onClick={e=>setSearchQuery(m)}
          className='titleItem'
        > 
          <FaSearch/>
          {m}
        </p>  
      )}
    )}   
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchList;

searchlist.css:
.Container_SearchList {
  background-color: white;
  width: 90.75%;
  position: absolute;
  top:2.7rem;
  height: fit-content;
  z-index: 91;
}

.titleItem {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.titleItem div p:hover {
  background-color: rgba(166,202,234,0.516);
}

enter image description here
When cursor is placed on the name, the color should change and the name should get selected

Do you want to add hover effect to full <p> tag or only on Name?

Look carefully at the selector you are using for the hover. Selecting an element with class titleItem comes first. This will select the p element. Then you ask it to look for a child div and then a grandchild p. There is no grandchild p of p. Use your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what HTML structure is being produced.

Issue is in your css. You are applying hover effect to <p> tag which child of div and that div child of element having class 'titleItem'.
In your code, there no such a structure matching and that's why it's not applying in your code.
But you have .titleItem class to <p> tag. then there is no need to use .titleItem div p:hover with div and p, You can direct access <p> tag by class name .titleItem.
Please change your css as below in searchlist.css,
Before:
.titleItem div p:hover {
  background-color: rgba(166,202,234,0.516);
}

After update:
.titleItem:hover {
  background-color: rgba(166,202,234,0.516);
}


Your solution may or may not be the correct one (we don’t know whether OP want the hover to act on the whole p or just the icon) but your explanation is not clear.

What I answered is based on his code as he mentioned about the issue and whatever you have explained in above comment that's the same thing I have replicated in my answer @AHaworth

I think it's better you explain to OP why there is no need to use .titleItem div p:hover, this is why your explanation is not clear
